# Не получается стащить фичу с сайта (CSS + js)

Tags: javascript, css

Собственно сайт

http://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com/

По нажатии кнопки происходит анимация справа, которая очень понравилась.

Скачал саму страницу, файлы min.css и min.js, но ничего не сработало. 
Почти ничего. Если из исходника страницы удалить некоторый встроенный js то какие-то признаки жизни оно подаёт непосредственно из css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот релевантный css-код (правило для `#right#right` я добавил для изменения позиционирования блока, остальное неизменно). Содержимое блоков заменил скриншотами, чтобы не тащить лишний код.

```js
$("body").click(function () {
  $("#right").toggleClass("flipped");
})
```

```css
#right#right {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

/*************************************************/

#right {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 380px;
    padding: 10px 18px 20px;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 870px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -o-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
}

#palettes, #reset-button, #right {
    position: absolute;
}

#code {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#code, #settings-container {
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transition: .6s;
    -webkit-transition: .6s;
    -o-transition: .6s;
    transition: 600ms 0ms;
}

#code {
    bottom: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}

#code, pre {
    position: absolute;
}

/*************************************************/

.flipped#right {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flipped #settings-container {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}

.flipped #code {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
    transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right">
  <div id="settings-container">
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/hw6ZB.png">
  </div>
  <div id="code">
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/md1NU.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Написано довольно чисто, кроме префиксов даже поудалять почти нечего...

Answer (score 5):

Потому что тырить надо не бездумно, а творчески. Вот как это работает:

```js
$('#cont').click(e => $('#cont').toggleClass('flipped'))
```

```css
#code, #settings-container {
    background: red;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: .6s;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
}
#code {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: green;
}

.flipped #settings-container {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
.flipped #code {
    transform: rotateY(0)scale(1);
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont" class=""> 
  <div id="settings-container">1</div>
  <div id="code">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.wrapper').toggleClass('flipped')
});
```

```css
#code,#settings-container {
    -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-transition:.6s;
    -webkit-transition:.6s;
    -o-transition:.6s;
    transition:.6s
}

#code {
    -moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    -o-transform:rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    transform:rotateY(-180deg)scale(.1)translateY(-70px);
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

.flipped #settings-container {
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    transform:rotateY(180deg)scale(.7);
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0
}

.flipped #code {
    -moz-transform:rotateY(0)scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(0)scale(1);
    -o-transform:rotateY(0)scale(1);
    transform:rotateY(0)scale(1);
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
    z-index:5;
    display:block
}

.wrapper{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="settings-container">Настройки</div>
    <div id="code">Код</div>
</div>

<button>Флипнунть</button>
```

Comment: Может быть, у тебя содержимое слишком мелкое, но я не вижу того же эффекта ухода вдаль, как у них. В сниппете как будто бы всё горизонтально переворачивается.

Comment: @Qwertiy я вот сейчас пробую, вроде эффект такой же